# Userscript works in Tampermonkey but not when loaded as an unpackaged extension in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, userscripts, tampermonkey

I recently created a userscript that allows the use of twitch.tv emotes on hitbox.tv. The userscript works completely fine in Tampermonkey for Chrome, however, when I try to load the unpackaged script and manifest files to create a chrome extension, it doesn't work. I don't know what might be causing the problem so if any of you guys could give me some support, it would be greatly appreciated.

- [465792.user.js](http://pastebin.com/tzLP08x2)
- [manifest.json](http://pastebin.com/KLJnywg9)

Thanks in advanced! If you need any more information, please just ask and I will try and provide some more.

-Tom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manifest:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [ {
        "exclude_globs":    [  ],
        "include_globs":    [ "*" ],
        "js":               [ "465792.user.js" ],
        "matches":          [   "http://hitbox.tv/*",
                                "https://hitbox.tv/*"
                            ]
    } ],
    "description":  "Allows the use of Twitch emotes on Hitbox.",
        "icons": { "128": "icon128.png" },
    "name":         "Hitbox Emotes",
    "version":      "1.1.4"
}
```

Your content script:

```
emotify.emoticons("",yourHundredLineObject);
```

I see two things that could be causing problems:

1. The websitee hitbox.tv prepended a www. to the url, which doesn't match what you listed.  I think you want `matches: ["*://*.hitbox.tv/"]` ([reference](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns)).  Your globs also don't appear to be doing anything, and can be removed.
2. Your content script is trying to use the hitbox defined function `emotify.emoticons`.  [Isolated worlds](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment) will prevent this.  In order to call the function, you'll need to have a different content script write `<script src="465792.user.js"></script>` into the webpage ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879)).